# Merging cells across columns in a table

Tags: tables, spacing

Hi want to create a table in which two cells should be merged horizontally.The output table should looks like this:

[image]

I have tried it like that

```
\begin{table}[t]\small
\centering
\caption{Technical Characteristics of Hyperspectral Imaging System.}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
      Patch Size& & CNN& & HOG\\
\hline
       & Training & Testing & Training & Testing\\
 \hline
 500 x 500  &  99.43    & 94.72 & 83.28 & 74.34\\
 \hline

\end{tabular}
\label{camera}
\end{table}
```

But it didn't work

Comment: That table doesn't have any rows which are merged. Do you mean columns? Can you please make your code snippet into something compilable? Use `\multicolumn{<number>}{<specifier>}{<content>}` if you want to merge *columns*, rather than rows, as the image suggests.

Comment: E.g. `\mulicolumn{2}{c}{ANN}` or whatever.

Comment: Sorry its multi column.. where i can add `\mulicolumn{2}{c}{ANN}`?

Comment: You just put it where you would otherwise put `ANN` if you wanted just one column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @cfr has noted in a comment, the `\multicolumn` directive can be used to "merge" several cells across columns. E.g.,

```
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Some text}
```

centers the string "Some text" across 2 columns.

When using `\multicolumn`, do be aware that this directive completely replaces the default column properties. This means that if the default properties of the 2 columns in question include being bordered by a vertical line on the right, and if you wish the merged cells to be bordered by a vertical line on the right, it's necessary to write

```
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Some text}
```

to add the vertical line to the right of the combined cells.

You may also want to familiarize yourself with ways to make the look of the table easier on your readers' eyes. If you want to stick with lots of vertical and horizontal rules, at least increase the vertical spacing a bit, say by setting `\extrarowheight` to a nonzero length. (`2pt` is usually enough.) Or, go ahead and delete all vertical rules and use fewer, but well-spaced horizontal rules. Your readers will almost certainly appreciate the resulting open and inviting "look" -- and they may well reward your effort by actually looking at what's *inside* the table...

The following screenshot and code illustrate these points.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}    % for \extrarowheight macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \toprule, \midrule, \cmidrule & \bottomrule macros
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering

\caption{Initial ``look''} 
\label{camera:1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
      Patch Size& & CNN& & HOG\\
 \hline
       & Training & Testing & Training & Testing\\
 \hline
 500 x 500  &  99.43    & 94.72 & 83.28 & 74.34\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\caption{Two \texttt{\string\multicolumn} directives} \label{camera:2}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
 Patch Size & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{CNN} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{HOG}\\
 \hline
            & Training & Testing & Training & Testing\\
 \hline
 500 x 500  &  99.43    & 94.72 & 83.28 & 74.34\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}


\bigskip
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a less-cramped look
\caption{A less-cramped look; ``$\times$'' rather than ``x''} 
\label{camera:3}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
 Patch Size & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{CNN} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{HOG}\\
 \hline
            & Training & Testing & Training & Testing\\
 \hline
 500 $\times$ 500  &  99.43    & 94.72 & 83.28 & 74.34\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
\setlength\extrarowheight{0pt} % reset to default value
\caption{A much more open look} 
\label{camera:4}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ccccc @{}} % note: no vertical bars at all
 \toprule % not \hline
 Patch Size & \multicolumn{2}{c}{CNN} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{HOG}\\
 \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(l){4-5}
            & Training & Testing & Training & Testing\\
 \midrule % not \hline
 500 $\times$ 500  &  99.43    & 94.72 & 83.28 & 74.34\\
 \bottomrule % not \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: how can I merge the two rows of 'Patch size'